# Qt Resources under Linux

Tags: c++, qt, resources

I want to use Qt Resources file .qrc to load resources to my soft. Under Windows, it works perfectly, but under Linux (Ubuntu 12.10), it doesn't work at all.

Here is a part of my resources.qrc file :

```
<qresource prefix="/ressources">
    <file alias="style">ressources/style.css</file>
</qresource>
```

When I open this file in my code I make something like that :

```
QFile file(":/ressources/style.css");

if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    qDebug() << "open fail";
    return ;
}
```

open() method is unable to open that file properly.

Have you an idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: Should that prefix attribute be there ? Or are your style files really at /ressources/ressources/style.css ? I think that it works for you on Windows by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified `"style"` as the alias, so you can only open it with:

```
QFile file(":/ressources/style");
```

However, since the prefix you specified is identical to the physical directory name, why don't you just do this instead:

```
<qresource>
    <file>ressources/style.css</file>
</qresource>
```